# Arduino sensor data recombined and published on master computer

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I having trouble publishing LaserScan data directly from an Arduinio Mega 2560, is there an example where data is published to the Master in a simpler format and then recombined on the master into the standard Laserscan message type and republished?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214736/arduino-sensor-data-recombined-and-published-on-master-computer/) by [charlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4007/charlie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_diff_drive/blob/master/src/odomlite_to_odom.cpp) is an example used for a Imu message. Not sure it will help you though.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0